# Выполняю задачу в AsynkTask, но как в нём же открыть поток для загрузки картинки?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-imageview

Вот код

```
public class PromoProductsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String ServletURL = "здесь адрес сервера";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promo_products);

    // получаем Intent и название магазина, которое он хранит
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String shopName = intent.getStringExtra("shopName");

    new ServletTask().execute(shopName);
}

private class ServletTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Product>>{

    @Override
    protected List<Product> doInBackground(String... params) {
        //String shopName = params[0];
        String shopName = "all";
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(ServletURL +shopName);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String outputString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            JSONArray output = new JSONArray(outputString);
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) output.get(i);
                    Product product = new Product(object.getString("productName"), object.getString("newPrice"),
                            object.getString("startPromo"), object.getString("endPromo"), object.getString("urlPhoto"));
                    productList.add(product);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return productList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Product> productList) {
        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemLayout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        for (Product p : productList){
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, itemLayout, false);
            // поле с названием продукта
            TextView product_name_tv = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.product_name_tv);
            product_name_tv.setText(p.getProductName());
            // поле с новой ценой продукта
            TextView new_price_tv = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.new_price_tv);
            new_price_tv.setText(p.getNewPrice());
            // поле с датой начала акции
            TextView start_promo_tv = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.start_promo_tv);
            start_promo_tv.setText(p.getProductName());
            // поле с датой конца акции
            TextView end_promo_tv = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.end_promo_tv);
            end_promo_tv.setText(p.getProductName());
            // поле с картинкой товара
            ImageView product_photo = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.product_photo);
            try {
                product_photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(p.getUrlPhoto()).openConnection().getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // устанавливаем размеры каждого пункта с товаром и отображаем на экране
            item.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            itemLayout.addView(item);
        }
    }
}
```

}

В этом случае получаю NetworkOnMainThreadException, то есть требует ещё один поток?
Если же я от фонаря пишу

```
product_photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(p.getUrlPhoto()));
```

То вроде всё работает, но вместо картинки кракозябры. В стеке пишет, что не может декодировать картинку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как загрузить картинку в ImageView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

метод `onPostExecute` выполняется в основном (UI) потоке. Засим, когда вы обращаетесь в сеть из него

> `product_photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(p.getUrlPhoto()).openConnection().getInputStream()));`

то закономерно получаете `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Если вам надо отобразить в `ImageView` картинку из сети, то у вас есть два варианта:

1. Запустить ещё одну задачу и в ней, в `doInBackground` загрузить картинку, чтобы назначить её `ImageView` в `onPostExecute`. Это **плохой** способ.
2. Воспользоваться одной из библиотек для сих целей. Например [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader):

   ```
   ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
   imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
   ```

Эта и аналогичные библиотеки позаботятся сами о потоках, асинхронности и прочем. И сократят кол-во кода в разы.

Comment: Решил задачу как раз первым способом. А если решать вторым способом, то Ваш код вставлять в то место, где я заполняю другие поля?

Comment: @UnknownPerson, в своё время и я этим путём ходил. И как прошедший его - советую свернуть таки на второй.

Comment: @UnknownPerson, почитайте краткие примеры использования библиотеки - там всё подробно расписано. В общем случае - код надо вставить туда, где вы хотите отобразить картинку.

Comment: Для того, чтобы использоать библиотеку Вам надо её подключить. А примеры по ипользоанию и настройке найдете на гитхабе в достаточном количестве. UniversalImageLoader очень хорошая штука, присоединяюсь к Юрию и очень Вам советую